# How to get ISO8601 seconds format from "date" in busybox?

Tags: date, embedded-linux, iso8601, busybox, arago

Without adequate examples I keep going around in circles to get the 'seconds' version of iso8601 printed out by 'date'. Please look at the help that is provided with date with busybox 1.22.1. I can't seem to understand the syntax required. Examples speaks louder than words in my experience and I haven't found anything that could be useful online.

Here is what I tried:

```
➤ date -I=seconds
➤ date -I SPEC='seconds'
➤ date -I seconds
➤ date -I='seconds'
➤ date -I 'seconds'
➤ date -I['seconds']
➤ date -I TIMESPEC='seconds'
➤ date -I TIMESPEC=seconds
```

**Note I have tried to use the Ubuntu version of date and was able to figure out how to get the iso8601=seconds format of date, but not in busybox...**

Here is what the help of date shows for Busybox 1.22.1:

```
BusyBox v1.22.1 (2014-09-26 07:33:17 CEST) multi-call binary.
Usage: date [OPTIONS] [+FMT] [TIME]
Display time (using +FMT), or set time
    [-s,--set] TIME Set time to TIME
    -u,--utc        Work in UTC (don't convert to local time)
    -R,--rfc-2822   Output RFC-2822 compliant date string
    -I[SPEC]        Output ISO-8601 compliant date string
                    SPEC='date' (default) for date only,
                    'hours', 'minutes', or 'seconds' for date and
                    time to the indicated precision
    -r,--reference FILE     Display last modification time of FILE
    -d,--date TIME  Display TIME, not 'now'
    -D FMT          Use FMT for -d TIME conversion
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The documentation (i.e., the help) is confusing and doesn't lead to a pleasant experience for a simple functionality. Instead the documentation needs to be re-written such that example command line inputs are also a part of help (at least to get the syntax down). In any case, I answered my own question.

The main and **very subtle** difference in one of my tries that I happened to miss:

```
➤ date -I 'seconds'
date: invalid date 'seconds'
```

Was off by a hair. It needed to remove the space:

```
➤ date -I'seconds'
2017-07-09T17:29:54-0400
```

Now busybox date is happy.

Comment: Remember that the Busybox documentation that is part of the commands is intentionally small. They are trying to fit the package into a very small size, and one of the ways they do this is by including very minimal documentation.

Comment: No I quite understand that but the way the tool is implemented, a few extra examples would help reduce confusion for users like me who aren't as familiar with the busybox tool set. Its some of these things that could make the tool more user friendly and would not bloat the package.